# Vue JS Call Server Side Method from Vue

Tags: vue.js, express, server-side-rendering, nodemailer

I would like to send a mail when I click a button.
I have stored the mail I have to send it to in: localStorage.plMail
My problem is, this ain't worked in my vue.js
So I have to make it server side in a .js file. But I have no idea after researching how I can call a method from a .js file from my vue. I've tried to call the method from my index.js file in the store folder but as I said, no clue.

This is a part of my vue so far:

```
    <template>
    ...
    
              <td class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" type="button" @click="cancelMail(row)">
                  <!-- &#10060; -->
                  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle" type="button" @click="makeMail(row)">
                  <!-- &#9989; -->
                  <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
    ...
    </template>
<script>
export default {
 name: "PlantsList",
components: { },
methods {
 cancelMail(data) {

},
makeMail(data){
this.$store.dispatch('makeMail', data);
}
}
}
</script>
```

^That's not the whole code, it's shorten for good reasons.

[image]

This is how my folder structure looks like^

and this my mail logic:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "**", // hostname
    secure: false, // use SSL
    port: **, // port for secure SMTP
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'anything@mail.com', // sender address
    to: 'anything2@mail.com', // list of receivers
    cc: '', // Comma separated list or an array
    subject: 'test', // Subject line
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
};

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('45 * * * * *', function() {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("/sendmail error");
            console.log(error);
            //res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + info.response);line
            socketTimeout: 30 * 1000 // 0.5 min: Time of inactivity until the connection is closed
            transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more essages
            //res.sendStatus(200);
        }
        transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
    });
})
```

Comment: You must make an HTTP request from your vue.js frontend to your express backend, for example using [`axios.post`](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro#axios-post-url-data-config).